# How to convert result from Date.now() to yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss ffff?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm looking for something like `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss ffff`

`Date.now()` returns the total of milliseconds (ex: 1431308705117).

How can I do this?

Comment: Just use the appropriate methods of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

Comment: `(new Date()).toISOString()`

Comment: [10 ways to format time and date with JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

Comment: Note that there is the [*ECMAScript Internationalization API Specification*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/) which specifies [*DateTimeFormat Objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-12). There is [*nascent support*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) in some modern browsers.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the `Date` constructor which takes in a number of milliseconds and converts it to a JavaScript date:

```
var d = new Date(Date.now());
d.toString() // returns "Sun May 10 2015 19:50:08 GMT-0600 (MDT)"
```

In reality, however, doing `Date(Date.now())` does the same thing as `Date()`, so you really only have to do this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toString() // returns "Sun May 10 2015 19:50:08 GMT-0600 (MDT)"
```

Comment: But that isn't the format that the OP wants, so not an answer.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [`Date().toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), i.e.:

```
let d = new Date().toISOString();
document.write(d);
```

---

### Output:

```
2023-12-06T12:19:33.038Z
```

---

### Demo:

```js
let d = new Date().toISOString();
document.write(d);
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use native JavaScript Date methods to achieve that or you can use a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

It is a simple as:

```
moment().format('YYYY/MM/D hh:mm:ss SSS')
```

If you are going use a lot of date formatting/parsing in your application then I definitely recommend using it.

Answer (score 10):

### Simple

```js
const DateNow = Date.now(); // 1602710690936
console.log(new Date(DateNow).toString()) // returns "Sun May 10 2015 19:50:08 GMT-0600 (MDT)"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function formatted_date()
{
   var result="";
   var d = new Date();
   result += d.getFullYear()+"/"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+d.getDate() + 
             " "+ d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+
             d.getSeconds()+" "+d.getMilliseconds();
   return result;
}

console.log(formatted_date())
```

Output: "2015/5/10 22:5:26 429"

Comment: Close, but single digit month and day numbers and time parts should have leading zeros. Two and three digit millisecond values probably should have too.

Comment: `.toString().padStart(2,0)` there. win.

Answer (score 2):

```
function millisecondsToHuman(ms) {
    const seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((ms / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor(ms / 1000 / 60 / 60);

    const humanized = [
       pad(hours.toString(), 2),
       pad(minutes.toString(), 2),
       pad(seconds.toString(), 2),
    ].join(':');

return humanized;
}

function pad(numberString, size) {
   let padded = numberString;
   while (padded.length < size) padded = `0${padded}`;
   return padded;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: use `new Date()` to get the date as JavaScript format as Sun Jul 12 2020 15:40:16 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

```
var d = new Date()
```

Step 2: use `.toString()` to convert to string and `.substr` string method to convert the previous string to "Jul 12 2020" and get rid of the rest

```
var d2 = d.toString().substr(4, 11)
```

Step 3: use `.slice` method to add '/' between dat, month and year to get Jul / 12 / 2020

```
var d3 = d2.slice(0, 3) + ' /' + d2.slice(3, 6) + ' /' + d2.slice(6))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const formattedDate = () => {
    d = new Date()
    cd = num => num.toString().padStart(2, 0)
    return d.getFullYear()+"/"+cd(d.getMonth() + 1)+"/"+cd(d.getDate()) + 
             " "+ cd(d.getHours())+":"+cd(d.getMinutes())+":"+
             cd(d.getSeconds())+" "+d.getMilliseconds()
}

console.log(formattedDate) //returns "2022/11/01 03:00:36 777"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
```

will get you an answer formatted like this: Sun May 10 2015 21:55:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

`var d = new Date();
var n = d.toJSON();`

will get you the answer formatted the way you were looking for it.

[Here is a great explanation of all the ways to manipulate the Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score -2):

I like the dataformat package:
you can install using:
npm i dataformat.

and you can use like that:

dateFormat(medicao.DataHora, 'UTC:HH:MM')